# Need help implementing Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree, and I came across this person's code and was basically trying to replicate it:

https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/44e1a9183ab0e931f729

with the only difference being that for some reason, this person did not make the insert or search functions as member functions of a Binary Search Tree class. I was basically trying to replicate his code, but I wanted those operations to be a part of the class (because it makes sense to me to do it that way...isn't that the way it should be done?)

So this is my code right now:

```
class BSTnode {

public:
BSTnode(int data) {

    BSTnode* right = nullptr;
    BSTnode* left = nullptr;
    this->data = data;
}


int data;
BSTnode* right;
BSTnode* left;

};

class BinarySearchTree{
public:
BinarySearchTree() {

    root = nullptr;

}

BSTnode* insert(BSTnode* root, int data) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        BSTnode* newNode = new BSTnode(data);
        root = newNode;
        return root;
    //  std::cout << root->data << endl;
    }

    if (data <= root->data) {

        root->left = insert(root->left, data);

    }
    else {

        root->right = insert(root->right, data);

    }

    return root;


}
public:
    BSTnode* root;

};
```

In my main I have the following:

```
BinarySearchTree bst;
bst.insert(bst.root, 4);

bst.insert(bst.root, 3);
bst.insert(bst.root, 4);
bst.insert(bst.root, 3);
bst.insert(bst.root, 2);


std::cout << bst.root->data << std::endl;
```

My first problem..I have the line of code

```
std::cout << bst.root->data << std::endl;
```

at the end of my main just to test if things are working as should. However, when I try to run this, the program crashes. When I debug that particular line, I get the error :

Unhandled exception at 0x00e6160a in BST_INTERVIEW.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.

Why is this happening? Secondly, 
my code basically just ends up making every element that I insert be the new root. When I debug, it says that everytime I insert, the condition root == nullptr is true, and so every new element is basically set as the root. I assume that when I'm calling insert after the first time, the root is not pointing to the actual root node of the BST, and I assume it is because I have to set this->root = newNode, as oppose to just root. But I feel like then I also have to add "this" at other points in the code, and I am just kinda confused. Can somebody help me make my code like the one in the link provided, but with BST being an actual object with member functions insert, search, etc...?

Edit: Per @Semyon Burov's answer, I changed the parameters for the insert function to be BSTnode*&. I also had to fix my constructor, which should have said this->left and this->right instead of BSTnode* right and BSTnode* left

Comment: You should inspect your program with a debugger. Looks like you are dereferencing an uninitialized or dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to change value of argument inside function, you should pass it as reference or pointer. And then you pass argument as pointer you can change not value of pointer, but to that it points.

```
BSTnode* insert(BSTnode* root, int data)
```

You pass `root` to function by value, so it changes only in scope of function.

Comment: I thought that if the parameter of a function was a pointer, like BSTnode* is in the insert function, it would automatically be passed as a pointer.

Comment: you pass pointer to memory that contains BSTnode and you can change values inside that memory, but you can't change pointer